# How to apply `call-interactively` to an interactive command that accepts the universal argument?

Tags: interactive, prefix-argument

I've read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html) on how to make interactive calls from within Elisp, but I still can't figure out how to pass the universal argument when using `call-interactively` on a command that recognizes the universal argument.

More specifically, I want to implement a function that, under certain conditions, should call the `shell` command interactively *with the universal argument*, so that, as a result, the prompt

```
Shell buffer (default *shell*):
```

will be visible in the minibuffer, and, once this prompt gets a response, the specified buffer will be created (if it doesn't exist already), and made the current buffer.

---

FWIW, I tried the following:

```
(universal-argument)
(call-interactively 'shell)
```

and

```
(setq prefix-arg (list 4))
(call-interactively 'shell)
```

...but I never saw the prompt `Shell buffer (default *shell*):`; instead, in all cases, the `shell` command ran exactly as if it had been called *without* the universal argument.  (I really don't know what I'm doing here, so my blind attempts above were made with conscious disregard of the documentation's prescient [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html#index-universal_002dargument).)

Comment: Try `(let ((current-prefix-arg 4)) (call-interactively 'shell))`

Comment: Thank you!  I'll gladly accept this as the answer if you care to post it as such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to `shell`'s interactive form, as long as `current-prefix-arg` is non-nil, `shell` will ask user a buffer to use, so you can set `current-prefix-arg` to non-nil (4 is used in following as an example):

```
(let ((current-prefix-arg 4))
  (call-interactively 'shell))
```

or simulate executing `shell` with a prefix 4 (<kbd>M-4 M-x shell</kbd>):

```
(execute-extended-command 4 "shell")
```

Comment: Just a tiny quibble: if one is going to use a truthy value other than plain old `t`, shouldn't that be `(list 4)` (or `'(4)` if you prefer)?  I realize that the current version of `shell` does not care about the difference between `4` and `(list 4)` (it cares only that the value is non-`nil`), but future versions might.

Comment: `4` simulates `M-4 M-x shell`, `'(4)` simulates `C-u M-x shell`