# How to specify prefix argument in key binding

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

The description of `C-x C-e` mentions:

> ...Interactively, with a non '-' prefix argument, print output into current buffer.

I understand this to mean this logic is triggered when I issue `C-u C-x C-e`, but how would I bind this to `C-c c`? How do I specify the prefix in the binding?

Same for `C-SPC`:

> With prefix argument (e.g., C-u C-SPC), jump to the mark, and set the mark from position popped off the local mark ring (this does not affect the global mark ring).

My normal binding looks like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c ,") 'pop-global-mark)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply \`call-interactively\` to an interactive command that accepts the universal argument?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21626/how-to-apply-call-interactively-to-an-interactive-command-that-accepts-the-uni)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>C-u</kbd> invokes the function `universal-argument`, and you want
to ensure that `eval-last-sexp` is called as if you invoked it
interactively, which is done with `call-interactively`. You can
simulate `universal-argument` by let-binding `current-prefix-arg`.

Putting that all together for `C-u C-x C-e`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (let ((current-prefix-arg 1))
                                  (call-interactively #'eval-last-sexp))))
```

For `C-u C-SPC`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c ,") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
                                  (call-interactively #'set-mark-command))))
```

Strictly speaking, as @NickD points out, `current-prefix-arg` should be bound to `'(4)` to be exactly equivalent to `C-u`, but for `eval-last-sexp` that doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to emulate `C-u`, then `current-prefix-arg` should be set to `(4)` - no? `1` emulates `C-u 1`.

Comment: It depends on the function you're calling. If it just checks whether or not there is a prefix arg, it doesn't matter. I'll clarify the answer

Answer (score 0):

@rpluim gives us the answer and inspires me to produce this handy-dandy Lisp macro. (I'm only presenting it as an "answer" to get the formatting)

```
(cl-defmacro ph/defprefixed (command &key (prefix 4) no-read-only)
  `(defun ,(intern (format "ph/prefixed-%s" command)) ()
     ,(format "Execute `%s' with prefix argument." command)
     (interactive ,(when no-read-only "*"))
     (let ((current-prefix-arg (list ,prefix)))
       (call-interactively (function ,command)))))
```

Used thus:

```
(ph/defprefixed set-mark-command)
```

it expands to this:

```
(defun ph/prefixed-set-mark-command ()
  "Execute `set-mark-command' with prefix argument."
  (interactive nil) ; nil is ignored
  (let
    ((current-prefix-arg (list 4)))
    (call-interactively
        (function set-mark-command))))
```

And thus:

```
(ph/defprefixed eval-last-sexp :no-read-only t)
```

Expansion:

```
(defun ph/prefixed-eval-last-sexp ()
  "Execute `eval-last-sexp' with prefix argument."
  (interactive "*")
  (let
    ((current-prefix-arg (list 4)))
    (call-interactively
        (function eval-last-sexp))))
```