# Preview all LaTeX fragments in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

How can I call `org-toggle-latex-fragment` on all LaTeX fragments in an Org mode doc? I'm coming from Vim, so my instinct is to put something in the `init.el` that loops through the document and looks for `$` and `\[` to call `org-toggle-latex-fragment` on if the file extension is `.org`. How can I implement this, and is this generally a good approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org-toggle-latex-fragment` is obsolete since Org 9.3. Use `org-latex-preview`.

To preview all latex fragments in the buffer pass `C-u` twice before calling `org-latex-preview`. Note that a single `C-u` before `org-latex-preview` actually removes all previews. For instance, I set the keybinding `C-f5` to `org-latex-preview` then `C-u C-f5` removes all previews and `C-u C-u C-f5` preview latex fragments on the whole buffer.

Note: `org-toggle-latex-fragment` has the same behavior, in case you are using an org-mode version before 9.3.

---

You might be also interested in [org-fragtog](https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog).

> Automatically toggle org-mode latex fragment previews as the cursor enters and exits them

Comment: Is it also possible to set `C-f5` to what `C-u C-u org-latex-preview` does directly? If so, how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can set keybindings to lambda functions and call `org-latex-preview` in a lambda function (or create a named function). The trick part is passing `C-u C-u` programmatically. Maybe [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21626/how-to-apply-call-interactively-to-an-interactive-command-that-accepts-the-uni) can help.